# Can i apply a style to a parent element

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Style parent li on child li:hover.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792689/style-parent-li-on-child-lihover)
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

I have a nave menu.

On `li a:hover` the `#drop-down-menu` appears.

Can I apply a style to the `li a` while hovering over the drop down menu?
Can you apply a style to the parent element while hovering over the child element?

i.e. I want a `border-bottom:2px solid #ffffff;` to appear under the `li a`, while i am hovering over the `#drop-down-menu`.

Can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use javascript for this. CSS doesn't allow any way to select a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

If your anchor is - or can be - fullsize (i.e. the size of the list item), then you can use:

```
li:hover
```

Answer (score 0):

No. CSS doesn't work that way. You can only go down.

However, if you have your HTML structured properly, you can achieve the effect you're going for.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<ul id="main">
  <li><a href="link.php">A dropdown</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
       <li><a href="link2.php">A submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can have the following CSS, and it should work:

```
#main li:hover a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Here's a (very) rough Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4cpTV/)