# Style parent li when hovering child li

Tags: jquery

I've been reading this thread: [Style parent li on child li:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792689/style-parent-li-on-child-lihover) and trying to get it to work with my menu in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PJMyR/1/, but it keeps throwing syntax errors at me, and I can't figure out why.

Here is the code:

```
$('li.parent ul li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('li.parent').addClass('highlighted');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().closest('li.parent').removeClass('highlighted');
});
```

Best regards
Martin

Comment: Can you post the 'syntax errors' that you are getting?

Comment: You need to include jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/PJMyR/2/

Comment: If you get "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined ": You forgot to add jQuery.

Comment: What errors are you getting? seems to be working ok in chrome.

Comment: You have to include jquery library and push all your code in $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: That seems to it. Emberrasing.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine . Use `.toggleClass` for make your code simpler

```
$(function() {

    $('li.parent ul li').hover(function() {

        $(this).closest('li.parent').toggleClass('highlighted');

      });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PJMyR/3/)

Comment: You could also remove the `.parent()` bit