# Applying style to td that is contained in tr

Tags: html, css

I have such issue, I have something like that:

```
    <tr>
      <td class="someclass">
        <input />
      </td>
    ...
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
     ..
    </tr>
```

I want to override "someclass" css class that will be applied only to first `<td>` with `<input>`. How can I do it? Maybe with parent specification or something like that? Note: I can't add new classes

Comment: can u  used to  jquery

Comment: so you just want to re-style the `td.someclass`?

Comment: please elaborate what you want exactly??

Comment: This is a variation of the CSS parent selector question. See potential work arounds in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792689/style-parent-li-on-child-lihover

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
table tr > td:first-child input{
   property: value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css pseudo class **`first-child`**

> **Supported from IE7 +**

```css
.someclass{background:red;}
#table1 tr > td:first-child {background:blue;}
```

```html
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td class="someclass">One</td>
<td>Two</td>
<td>Three</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Please refer this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)  to know more about css selectors